# Sending generated email. Trouble with header

Tags: email, email-headers, eml

I'm trying to send some html in a generated email that looks something like this:

```
X-Sender: XXXX@xxxx.com
X-Receiver: XXXX@xxxx.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: XXXXXXX@xxxx.com
To: XXXXX@xxxx.com
Date: 9 Dec 2010 10:55:52 -0800
Subject: Test email
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<p>Click on the link below</p><p><a href="http://www.mysite.com">Click Here</a></p>
```

The email sends but for some reason the link tag doesn't show up. I'm thinking it has something to do with the the content type. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this Content-Type: "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"

It should allow your HTML to be handled properly.

Comment: you might need to format your html properly.  if that's all you got then it would expect the html, head, and body tags which are missing.  Just because it rendered part doesn't mean it was formatted properly.

Comment: I'm looking at my template and I don't have Content-Transfer-Encoding in mine.  Not sure if it is necessary.